# Call javascript function from anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html

I am calling javascript function from anchor tag. But problem is i am rendering anchor tag from code rendering block. From here i am fetching a value from database and sending to the function as a parameter. My code is:

```
<div>
<%-- <h3> Curent </h3>--%>
<ul>
<%                                
   if (_dsContent.Tables.Count == 0)
      return;
   System.Collections.Generic.List<string> lstCat =
   new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();

   foreach (System.Data.DataTable table in _dsContent.Tables)
   {
    foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
     if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(row["ContentPart"])))
       {
         if (Convert.ToString(row["Content"]).Length > 200)
           content = Convert.ToString(row["Content"]).Substring(0, 200);
         else
           content = Convert.ToString(row["Content"]);
       }
     else
       {
       if (Convert.ToString(row["ContentPart"]).Length > 200)
        content = Convert.ToString(row["ContentPart"]).Substring(0, 200);
       else
         content = Convert.ToString(row["ContentPart"]);
       }                       

string catStr = Convert.ToString(row["categoryString"]);
string[] arrayCat = new string[2];

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(catStr))
{
  arrayCat = catStr.Split(',');
}
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(content))
{
  if (!lstCat.Contains(arrayCat[1]))
   {
 Response.Write("<div style='color:Red; font-weight:
 bold;font-size:20px'>" + arrayCat[1] + "</div>");
 lstCat.Add(arrayCat[1]);
 }

 Response.Write("<li>");
 Response.Write("<div style='background-
 color:#DFD48D'>Posted On - " + row["InsertionDate"] + "</div>");

 Response.Write("<div style='font-weight: bold;text-
 align:justify'>'" + row["Header"] + "'</div>");
 Response.Write("<div style='font-size: small'>Date - '" + row["Date"] + "'</div>");
 Response.Write("<div style='text-align:justify'>");
 Response.Write(content);

 string jud = Convert.ToString(row["Content"]);

 Response.Write("");

 Response.Write("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <a href='#' runat='server' onclick=ShowContent()>");

 Response.Write("Read More...");
 Response.Write("</a>");

 Response.Write("</div>");
 Response.Write("</li></br>");
 }
 }
 }                               
    %>

 </ul>
 </div>
```

here i am not able to send string jud as parameter.
my javascript function is

```
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function ShowContent(jud) {

        PageMethods.ShowContent(jud,Success, Failure);

    }
    function Success(result) {
        window.open('showcontent.aspx', null,'left=200, top=30, height=550, width= 500, 
         status=no, resizable= yes, scrollbars= yes,toolbar= no,location= no, menubar=
                 no');
    }
    function Failure(error) {
        alert(error);
    }

   </script>
```

Please guid.
Thanks

Comment: Please improve upon the indentation of your code!

Comment: i am so sorry for my poor indentation, i will take care of this for next.

Comment: I am trying to pass string jud from anchor tag like, onclick=showcontent('"+jud+"'). But this is writing whole content on page and not let me pass this.

Answer (score 0):

There should be quotes around your `onclick`.

```
Response.Write("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  <a href='#' runat='server' onclick='ShowContent()'>");
```

You have to pass a parameter to the `ShowContent` function as stated in the declaration.

```
function ShowContent(jud)
```

Comment: i have tried like this..... Response.Write("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='#' runat='server' onclick='ShowContent('"+jud+"')'>");  But this is not writing proper anchor tag on html

Comment: @Abhi Shouldn't it be `onclick='ShowContent("+jud+")'`

Comment: I tried that but no improvement. This is writing the jud value after anchor tag upto ShowContent("+jud, then this is writing )'. And thus no proper anchor tag like Read More.... But like                                                                              "
')'>Read More...